# Ajax result always returns error even if function is successful

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I have an Ajax function that looks like this

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@IGT.baseUrl/SODetailsAjax/AddUnits",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                so_id: @Int32.Parse(Request["orderId"]),
                site_id: site,
                addItem_id: items,
                addItem_qty: itemsqty,
                addItem_disc: itemsdisc,
                addComp_id: comps,
                addComp_qty: compsqty,
                addComp_disc: compsdisc,
                addPart_id: parts,
                addPart_qty: partsqty,
                addPart_disc: partsdisc
            },
            success: function (data) {
             if(data.success === "False"){
                var errorMessage = data.Message;      
                alert("Error:" + errorMessage);
                return;
             }
             if(data.success === "True"){
                location.href = "../SalesOrders/Details?id=@so.ID";
             }            
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("Error:" + error);
            }
        });
```

And I have a JSON ActionResult method that does this in it.

```
  if (!canCreate)
                    {                 
                            var errorMessage = string.Join(",", errors);
                            var stock = new { success = "False", Message = errorMessage };
                            return Json(stock, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                                       
                    }
  else
                    {

                            var result = new { success = "True" };
                            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
```

But everytime Success is true it returns an error message saying "Error:Not defined" when I click "OK" it proceeds. But how can I make it so it just proceeds instead of sending an error message?

Comment: A single `=` assigns a value. Use `==` or `===` for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors. In your `if (data.Success = "false")` statement, this is not a condition. This is an assignment. You should do `if (data.success === "false")` this would check for the condition. Also note that "success" is all lower case because it's converted to Json. You also need to note that "False" does not equal "false" so you must pick a casing. Either do "False"/"True" in both c# and JavaScript or "false"/"true".

Comment: I did those changes now the function doesn't proceed at all. I used to get an error message if the condition was false. Now I don't receive anything. And I used to be able to atleast proceed if the condition was true, just received error message. Now it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Nevermind it works! I guess sometimes it just doesn't run through the first time correctly. Thanks spider